# Calling javascript elements within php code

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

Can JavaScript elements be recognized if they are within  tags? So like for example:

```
<?php
  $username = "maniacal";
  echo "<p class='welcome' id='greeting'>Hi, Welcome to the site!!</p>"
?>
```

So thats what my php looks like. Then from that can I call the  'greeting' element from another part of the code like `document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML='Greetings ' + name + '!';` ?

Comment: Your questions isn't clear - where do you want to do this, how, and what for?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can
eg.

```
 <?php
   $username = "maniacal"; 
   echo"<p class='welcome' id='greeting'>Hi, Welcome to the site!!</p>" ;
?>
<script>
  document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML="Hi <?php echo $username?>, welcome to the site";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes ofourse you can do it but you should add your javascript code in document.ready tag because your

```
<p class='welcome' id='greeting'>Hi, Welcome to the site!!</p>
```

should be placed on your html page before you call it by --> getElementById

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code :

**Using PHP :**

```
 $username = "maniacal"; 
 echo"<p class='welcome' id='greeting'>Hi, "$username" Welcome to the site!!</p>" ;
```

**OR Using Javascript :**

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML="Hi <?php echo $username?>, welcome to the site";
</script>
```